# Function to_date and BETWEEN slow query on a large table

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-performance, database-indexes

I am using PostgreSQL, and I use the following query:

```
SELECT r.name,count(r.name)
from rooms r
where to_date(dateinput,'YYYYMMDD') between r.start_date and r.end_date
or to_char(r.end_time,'HH24:MI:SS')<> '00:00:00')
and (r.name in ('nameA','nameB'))
group by r.name
```

When my table has 900.000 rows, it is very slow. I create an index on the columns `start_date`, `end_date` and `name`. It executes in 1543 ms. `end_time` is of data type `time without time zone`.

But when I change the query to

```
SELECT r.name,count(r.name)
from rooms r
where cast(dateinput as date) >= r.start_date
  and cast(dateinput as date) < r.end_date
  and r.name in ('nameA','nameB')
or to_char(r.end_time,'HH24:MI:SS')<> '00:00:00')
and (r.name in ('nameA','nameB'))
group by r.name
```

the execution time is reduced to 786 ms. I think `to_date` and `between` make the index inoperable. I can't find any documentation or example that explains why the index cannot be used when using `to_date` and `between`. I don't know why modifying the query reduces the time to 786 ms. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The index cannot be used for either query, and the time difference might be by accident or because the second query found more of the table in cache than the first. Both queries you show are syntactically incorrect and will not run. Please show the correct queries!

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe i just edit query. Please help

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe because the second query found more of the table in cache than the first. => i don't understand this. Could you explain ? Why you know this

Comment: Do `nameA` and `nameB` change or are they always the same?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe it fixed nameA and nameB . Not change.

Comment: Could you show us the query plan? Use EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) to create one. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html

Comment: @FrankHeikens well i using explain but it cannot show me any index

Comment: EXPLAIN shows you what the database is doing, how it executes your query. That is vital information for performance optimisation, without it, we're blind. Could you show us the query plan?

Comment: @FrankHeikens In this case it is clear that the database can only do a sequential scan. But it would of course be interesting how selective the individual conditions are.

Comment: If `end_time` is a `time` column then compare it with a time value: `r.end_time <> time '00:00:00'`. Note that your two queries are not doing the same thing

Comment: Why don't you merge `end_date` and `end_time` into a single `timestamp` column? Then it might be possible to get rid of the strange `or end_time <> '00:00'` condition.

Answer (score 1):

The index cannot be used for either query, and the difference in execution time is probably because the first query had to read more data from disk, while they were already cached in RAM (shared buffers) during the second query.

The strange `OR` condition makes it difficult to make this query efficient, and `to_char(r.end_time,'HH24:MI:SS')` is impossible to index (and I don't understand its meaning).

You will have to rewrite the query without `OR` (use a `UNION`) and express the condition on `end_time` differently, then you can use indexes to speed it up.

I would rewrite the query like this:

```
SELECT r.name, count(r.name)
FROM (SELECT r.name
      FROM rooms r
      WHERE to_date(dateinput,'YYYYMMDD') <@ daterange(r.start_date, r.end_date, '[]')
        AND r.name IN ('nameA','nameB')
      UNION
      SELECT r.name
      FROM rooms r
      WHERE r.end_time <> TIME '00:00:00'
        AND r.name IN ('nameA','nameB')
     ) AS r
GROUP BY r.name;
```

These indexes could help:

```
CREATE INDEX ON rooms USING gist (daterange(r.start_date, r.end_date, '[]')) WHERE r.name IN ('nameA','nameB');

CREATE INDEX ON rooms (name) WHERE r.end_time <> TIME '00:00:00' AND r.name IN ('nameA','nameB');
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer . My end_time with type : time without time zone. I using to_char(r.end_time,'HH24:MI:SS') because i want convert it to char and compare it to begin time. So can you explain why when i remove function to_date my query reduce a lot time. Any suggest for rewrite query

Comment: I have added suggestions to the answer.

Comment: Thanks you for suggestions. It help me so much. So i have a question ?  I can using create index on rooms using btree ? Why i need USING gist here

Comment: Because the index is on a range type, which does not support B-tree indexes.